# Scroll area by mouse drag in qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, scrollview, drag, qooxdoo

Is there any built in possibily to drag content inside container by dragging for example `qx.ui.container.Scroll`? I found there are `qx.ui.core.MDragDropScrolling` and  `qx.ui.core.DragDropScrolling` but don't know that is what I am looking for.

Comment: do you mean that you have a widget inside a container and you want to use the mouse to reposition the widget?  Or that you want to drag a widget from outside the container, and drop it into the container?

Comment: @johnspackman I think the first one. The word reposition is confusing me. It is not drag actually, under the drag effect I meant an user press a left mouse button holding it moves it up, left and etc. Mouse pointer looks like grab. Doing that he can scroll content of container vertically or horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (eg copy and paste into the [Qooxdoo playground](http://qooxdoo.org/qxl.playground/#Hello%20World-ria)).

It traps the mouse movements and apply the relative movement of the mouse (while the button is down) to the scroll bars

```
// This is a little hack to persuade Chrome to always show the scroll bars
qx.bom.Stylesheet.createElement(
"::-webkit-scrollbar { -webkit-appearance: none; width: 7px; }\n" +
"::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { border-radius: 4px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5); }\n"
);

// This is a simple thing to add a border to our bigWidget
var border = new qx.ui.decoration.Decorator().set({
        width: 3,
        style: "solid",
        color: "black"
      });

// Creates a massive widget
var bigWidget = new qx.ui.core.Widget().set({
    minWidth: 2000,
    minHeight: 2000,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    decorator: border
});

// Scrollable area
var scrollable = new qx.ui.container.Scroll(bigWidget).set({
  scrollbar: [ "on", "on" ]
});

var mouseDown = false;
var mouseStartPos = null;
var widgetStartPos = null;

bigWidget.addListener("mousedown", evt => { 
  mouseDown = true; 
  mouseStartPos = { top: evt.getScreenTop(), left: evt.getScreenLeft() };
  widgetStartPos = { top: scrollable.getScrollX(), left: scrollable.getScrollY() };
});

bigWidget.addListener("mouseup", () => { 
  mouseDown = false; 
});

bigWidget.addListener("mousemove", evt => { 
  if (!mouseDown || !evt.isLeftPressed())
    return;

  let deltaPos = { top: mouseStartPos.top - evt.getScreenTop(), left: mouseStartPos.left - evt.getScreenLeft() };
  scrollable.scrollToX(widgetStartPos.left - deltaPos.left);
  scrollable.scrollToY(widgetStartPos.top - deltaPos.top);
  console.log("deltaPos=" + JSON.stringify(deltaPos) + ", mouseStartPos=" + JSON.stringify(mouseStartPos) + ", widgetStartPos=" + JSON.stringify(widgetStartPos));
});

var doc = this.getRoot();
doc.add(scrollable, {
  left : 0,
  top  : 0,
  right: 0, 
  bottom: 0
});
```

Comment: I wonder more about framework built in solution. Something like property or mixin with them I could just enable this feature.  I could write code like above but anyway thank you so much.